# why do all softphones fail to authenticate after receiving 401 unauthorized from Asterisk?

Tags: linux, networking, asterisk, voip, sip

When I attempt to connect to the Asterisk server from [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/), over a Cisco [router](http://www.cisco.com/web/consumer/support/modem_DPC3825.html), on the same network, Asterisk logs show the attempted connection:

```
<------------->
[Mar 23 20:01:34] VERBOSE[4067] chan_sip.c: [Mar 23 20:01:34] --- (8 headers 0 lines) ---
[Mar 23 20:01:34] NOTICE[4067] chan_sip.c: Outbound Registration: Expiry for nat5.babytel.ca is 55 sec (Scheduling reregistration in 40 s)
[Mar 23 20:01:34] VERBOSE[4067] chan_sip.c: [Mar 23 20:01:34] Really destroying SIP dialog '5e070a0021f200c72308ddad6fe2521c@192.168.0.99' Method: REGISTER
[Mar 23 20:02:01] VERBOSE[20423] manager.c: [Mar 23 20:02:01]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Mar 23 20:02:01] VERBOSE[20423] manager.c: [Mar 23 20:02:01]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Mar 23 20:02:06] VERBOSE[20436] manager.c: [Mar 23 20:02:06]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Mar 23 20:02:06] VERBOSE[20436] manager.c: [Mar 23 20:02:06]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Mar 23 20:02:10] VERBOSE[4067] chan_sip.c: [Mar 23 20:02:10]
<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.0.15:39462 --->
REGISTER sip:192.168.0.99 SIP/2.0
v: SIP/2.0/UDP 99.99.99.99:39462;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjiUEFUHN08Wvs9xG2Q9tzRMOxFYJ323dO
Route: <sip:192.168.0.99;transport=udp;lr>
Max-Forwards: 70
f: <sip:201@192.168.0.99>;tag=HVPwJ.kg.9MW6PypcpObrVPGC3l3B-Uh
t: <sip:201@192.168.0.99>
i: QIsF0rZ0wYvzKC9S2P0rWhnYGsQ9FQbI
CSeq: 56288 REGISTER
User-Agent: CSipSimple_v1-16/r2457
m: <sip:201@99.99.99.99:39462;ob>;+sip.ice
Expires: 900
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
l: 0

<------------->
[Mar 23 20:02:10] VERBOSE[4067] chan_sip.c: [Mar 23 20:02:10] --- (13 headers 0 lines) ---
[Mar 23 20:02:10] VERBOSE[4067] chan_sip.c: [Mar 23 20:02:10] Sending to 192.168.0.15:39462 (NAT)
[Mar 23 20:02:10] VERBOSE[4067] chan_sip.c: [Mar 23 20:02:10]
<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.0.15:39462 --->
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 99.99.99.99:39462;branch=z9hG4bKPjiUEFUHN08Wvs9xG2Q9tzRMOxFYJ323dO;received=192.168.0.15;rport=39462
From: <sip:201@192.168.0.99>;tag=HVPwJ.kg.9MW6PypcpObrVPGC3l3B-Uh
To: <sip:201@192.168.0.99>;tag=as0986faf4
Call-ID: QIsF0rZ0wYvzKC9S2P0rWhnYGsQ9FQbI
CSeq: 56288 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 1.8.29.0-vici
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="10600450"
Content-Length: 0
```

CSipSimple itself fails to connect to the local Asterisk server.

Because [Jitsi shows similar errors](http://lists.jitsi.org/pipermail/users/2015-March/009070.html), it doesn't seem to be client specific.  Because both Jitsi on a Mac and CSipSimple on an Android phone can make voice calls out, that, to my mind, positively eliminates a firewall on the router as a cause.

In the meantime, I've disabled the firewall on the server to eliminate that as a potential issue, which, admittedly, probably, wasn't necessary.

When Asterisk replies with `401 Unauthorized` how do I know why the connection is unauthorized?

The [full log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f4tJ8idBYBpFPwZq3asFcJMC4JYOfMRA3OmzQw6X8jw/edit?usp=sharing) is too large to post here.  While `sip set debug on` didn't provide any output, the output from that command is [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.telephony.pbx.asterisk.user/282940), although that was with Jitsi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 401 Unauthorized isn't an error: is how authentication mechanism works on SIP (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955400/sip-making-a-call-401-unauthorized) answer)

The line:

```
[Mar 23 20:02:10] NOTICE[4067] chan_sip.c: Registration from '<sip:201@192.168.0.99>' failed for '192.168.0.15:39462' - Wrong password
```

Seems clear: the password in your SIP client is wrong and the authentication doesn't succeed.
SIP password in sip.conf by the "secret" parameter inside your peer definition (201).